# designing android slidemenu screen.

Tags: android, android-sliding

I am able to show a slidemenu in application by adding the slidemenu library. I want to design my slidemenu like this

[image: this].

Please let me know any tutorial .Also I am able to show left slidemenu by the code `setBehindContentView(R.layout.slidemenu);`

How i can show a forward slide menu ?